# What should I do to get Mini P.E.K.K.A.?

Tags: clash-royale

I am in Arena 2, have 592 trophies, and I have had no luck finding the Mini P.E.K.K.A., even though I've opened a number of chests. What should I do to get Mini P.E.K.K.A.? I am trying to collect all commons and rares available for my arena.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Just keep playing, you will get it eventually.**

There is no short-cut to getting a mini pekka, or any other troop, directly.

You will get the mini pekka after a while of playing. Just be patient.

But if you really want a mini pekka, you can improve your odds of getting it, by buying chests like the giant chest, magical chest or super magical chest from in-game with real money.

Cards you have not yet unlocked **can be bought in the card shop**, so pop in everyday to check if the mini pekka is amongst one of the available cards to buy!

Because the mini pekka is a rare, the best odds of getting one will be by buying a super magical chest, because it is stated in-game that the super magical chest contains at least 115 rares (and 19 epics), thus you have a very high chance of getting a mini pekka in that chest.

Comment: Safe jacobus Mostert

Comment: Also is it a good idea to play with full slots however a crown chest Is available

Comment: Not true! You can buy a card from the Shop, even if you haven't unlocked it. For example, the Lumberjack did appear in my Shop, however I don't have it yet.

Comment: @John Thanks, I just realized it a few days ago. I can't believe that it took me so long to realize. I've been playing so long and I still didn't know XD